# .NET Fastest way to find similarity and difference of two files?

Tags: c#, .net, file, comparison

I am attempting to make a file comparison program, one of the features I would like to implement is to calculate the Similarity and Difference of the two files chosen. I would like this comparison to be fast (if possible) on large files. I am not sure what method should be used, but in the end I want a percentage.

Refer to [this gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etXIx.gif) to get a visual idea.

Comment: What's a "similar byte"?

Comment: Also your code a) isn't valid `c#` or anything, and b) calculated `a.Length * b.Length`

Comment: @millimoose Did this in a rush, I hope you get the gist of what I'm saying, if not, I'll try rephrase.

Comment: There is no "gist" to what you're saying. You're not providing a definition of what you mean by "similarity", and your code sample, even after filling in the blanks, doesn't do anything that would calculate anything I'd call "similarity". Provide an actual definition and preferrably some sample input and output and how you get from the former to the latter.

Comment: @millimoose I just fixed the code, by similarity I meant identicalness (two bytes that are the same), sorry.

Comment: So uh... If file 1 is `aaa`, and file 2 is `aba`, you want to say there are 6 similar bytes?

Comment: By similar do you mean two bytes at the same position in file to be equal? They way you've put it does not really make much sense. Given two regular files there is a "good chance" that for every byte x in a there is a an equal byte y in b. This way a "most of the time" will be similar to b. Unless you want to take the byte position into consideration.

Comment: How about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance between both files (based on bytes)?
Time = O(length1*length2), 
Space = O(min(length1,length2))

Comment: @millimoose I actually want to say there are two, in your case.

Comment: @kaptan I am sorry for my ignorance, but all I really want to do is generate a percentage of how simmilar two files are. Google mCcompare hackforums and register if you aren't already, and check out his program.

Comment: Um... SO doesn't work by you posting some vague description of something, being asked to clarify, and having you respond "Google this site, register there if you aren't already, and look at this program if you want to see what I'm trying to do.". I'm voting to put this question on hold until you can clearly explain what it is you're trying to do *here in your question* so that the question is useful to future users of this site. Questions should contain sufficient detail to be self-sufficient, without relying on external content to see what's being asked. Good luck.

Comment: You don't tell us what you mean by "similar files". And of course nobody is willing to register somewhere to find out what you might mean. Assuming that you already know what you mean you can just tell us.

Comment: Okay guys, I've reworded the question. I admit that my previous post was very very vague, as I don't have good explanatory skills, me being 13 aha .

Comment: "I'm not sure what method should be used" - well this here is the problem. You're the one that has to say that "inputs X and Y will give output Z", and you have to do this precisely. If you can't, figuring that part out should be what you're working on. For your use case, what will the correct behaviour of the program be?

Comment: @millimoose I'm not really sure what you mean. I said "I'm not sure what method should be used" because there may be other methods than byte comparisons that are faster, and I'm clueless on what others there may be.

Comment: WinDiff not good enough windiff.exe /?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to something like similarity as seen by a binary diff utility -- not a dumb byte-by-byte comparison. But hey, just for fun...

```
unsafe static long DumbDifference(string file1Path, string file2Path)
{
    // completely untested! also, add some using()s here.
    // also, map views in chunks if you plan to use it on large files.

    MemoryMappedFile file1 = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(
             file1Path, System.IO.FileMode.Open,
             null, 0, MemoryMappedFileAccess.Read);
    MemoryMappedFile file2 = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(
             file2Path, System.IO.FileMode.Open,
             null, 0, MemoryMappedFileAccess.Read);
    MemoryMappedViewAccessor view1 = file1.CreateViewAccessor();
    MemoryMappedViewAccessor view2 = file2.CreateViewAccessor();

    long length1 = checked((long)view1.SafeMemoryMappedViewHandle.ByteLength);
    long length2 = checked((long)view2.SafeMemoryMappedViewHandle.ByteLength);
    long minLength = Math.Min(length1, length2);

    byte* ptr1 = null, ptr2 = null;
    view1.SafeMemoryMappedViewHandle.AcquirePointer(ref ptr1);
    view2.SafeMemoryMappedViewHandle.AcquirePointer(ref ptr2);

    ulong differences = (ulong)Math.Abs(length1 - length2);

    for (long i = 0; i < minLength; ++i)
    {
        // if you expect your files to be pretty similar,
        // you could optimize this by comparing long-sized chunks.
        differences += ptr1[i] != ptr2[i] ? 1u : 0u;
    }

    return checked((long)differences);
}
```

Too bad .NET has no SIMD support built in.

Comment: SIMD support should be easy enough to get with interop.   Also, why did you tell the OP that a diff algorithm was what he needed, but then provided something else?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use linq this should be no problem.

```
var results = your1stEnumerable.Intersect(your2ndEnumerable);
```